# mknod on cifs samba : operation not permitted when pulling with docker

Tags: samba, docker, cifs

I have a smb share mounted in my linux box using cifs that seems to work. It is able to pull `gcc:8` docker image and download, verify and pull all layers of the image (I verified this to a pull of the image on a local drive).

I resolved an issue with creating symbolic links; The cifs mounted share is using file and dir access permissions *0777*, and I use a cifs argument int /etc/fstab called mfsymlinks to make softlinks work for docker.

The docker pulling has failed before by saying it could not create symlinks, while pulling one of the layers and it also failed once by not being able to 'mkdir', probably because of the access permissions not being permissive. I did not yet 'clean' the docker staging area on the disk, so maybe it could be a leftover of that failure?

Here are the last few lines of the docker pull process:

```
...
16ea0e8c8879: Pull complete
50024b0106d5: Pull complete
ff95660c6937: Pull complete
9c7d0e5c0bc2: Pull complete
29c4fb388fdf: Pull complete
f87845d1b3b4: Pull complete
adc3e1e98dd6: Pull complete
4dc8223d50f0: Pull complete
failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): failed to mknod("/usr/bin/g++", S_IFCHR, 0): operation not permitted
```

Given that only root is able to create new nodes (mknod) through kernel code calls (in this case, creating a node to store the g++ compiler within the docker layer), I started thinking that this issue has to do with the user permissions; either the gitlab-runner, the user-creddentials of the cifs mount, or the docker service, or something else?

Here's how that gitlab job initiates:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.5.0 (577f813d)
  on XYZ-for-project abcdefgh
Using Shell executor...
Running on XYZ...
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /mnt/share/NightlyBuild/abcdefgh/0/username/project/.git/
Checking out df111d72 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ docker login $IMAGE_PATH -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /home/gitlab-runner/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
$ docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 Server Version: 19.03.2
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: <unknown>
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 
 runc version: 
 init version: 
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 5.3.0-24-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu 19.10
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 7.775GiB
 Name: XYZ
 ID: 435N:UBGI:NS4Z:CX6F:GD2A:WMPT:4THN:FQQX:6NRU:VKJL:O7E2:V46F
 Docker Root Dir: /mnt/share/NightlyBuild/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
$ docker build -f Lin64-Base/Dockerfile -t docker-build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon    949MB

Step 1/37 : FROM gcc:8
8: Pulling from library/gcc
16ea0e8c8879: Pulling fs layer
50024b0106d5: Pulling fs layer
ff95660c6937: Pulling fs layer
9c7d0e5c0bc2: Pulling fs layer
29c4fb388fdf: Pulling fs layer
f87845d1b3b4: Pulling fs layer
adc3e1e98dd6: Pulling fs layer
4dc8223d50f0: Pulling fs layer
b601d78e8f0b: Pulling fs layer
f87845d1b3b4: Waiting
adc3e1e98dd6: Waiting
4dc8223d50f0: Waiting
b601d78e8f0b: Waiting
9c7d0e5c0bc2: Waiting
29c4fb388fdf: Waiting
50024b0106d5: Verifying Checksum
50024b0106d5: Download complete
...
```

** Update **

I mentioned that I did not 'clean' the docker stage area, but also on a fresh  docker home dir (replacing /var/lib/docker) the same behavior occurs, with the same error reported.

This is issue is such that I have to use a local ubuntu disk that lives inside a VirtualBox on Windows10 host. The partition has 150 GB available and is more than large enough, and the host has over 50 GB free disk size. So this seems like a solution, until [I run into](https://superuser.com/questions/1507607/host-win10-disk-size-reported-wrong-after-docker-builds-in-virtualbox-on-guest) [another issue](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=84711). The vanishing disk space occurs during a (ninja) c++ build of sources, during the docker build stage. The forum tags the thread as 'resolved' and mentions `chkdsk /f` as the solution, but it is actually the reboot of Windows that fixes the wrongly reported free disk size of the host. When the disk size seemingly seems to be under megabyte, Windows 10 freezes with a blue message screen saying it cannot continue. Of course, rebooting windows shuts down the Virtual Box, Ubuntu, gitlabrunner job and docker build, so that's clearly NOT a good solution.